# dashed border not working for UITableview cell's child view(dashed border width and hight not same as the view)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Here you can see the view which is inside the TableViewell:

[image]

Here is the code for adding dashed border:

```
func addDashedBorder() 
{ 
    let color = UIColor(displayP3Red: 178.0/255.0, green: 181.0/255.0, blue: 200.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    shapeLayer.bounds = shapeRect
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [6,3]
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shapeRect, cornerRadius: 4).cgPath
    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

I'm calling this function inside the awake from nib like this:
`view.addDashedBorder()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier approach...

Subclass `UIView` and put the border-related code inside it:

```
class DashedView: UIView {
    
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        let color = UIColor(displayP3Red: 178.0/255.0, green: 181.0/255.0, blue: 200.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
        shapeLayer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [6,3]
        
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 4).cgPath
        
    }

}
```

Now you don't need **any** sort of `view.addDashedBorder()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for issue:** You are calling your border adding code from awakeFromNib.

- Awake from is called when nib loaded, so that time your cell will not have the exact size for all subviews, when awakeFromNib gets called, all views have size as same as nib design. so awake from nib is the wrong place when you are setting or updating something which is related to size of any view.

**Solution:** The right place to do this is `func layoutSubviews()`

- layoutSubviews() gets called when the size of any subview will be changed or the frames of views/subviews gets updated first time.
- This is the right place to add border or your view, and make sure it will only one call of adding border because layoutSubviews will get multiple calls if the frame of any subview will change.**

> Reference:
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews

Comment: override func layoutSubviews() {
        print("layout working")
        super.layoutSubviews()
       view.addDashedBorder()
    }. i have tried this..but no changes yet

Comment: Minor correction: You need to create your shape layer once (in awakeFromNib is fine). You'll want to save the shape layer into an instance variable so you can reference it later. Then you need to build and install the path into the shape layer in layoutSubviews. (layoutSubviews can be called multiple times.)

Comment: override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let frameSize = imageVW.frame.size
        let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shapeRect, cornerRadius: 4).cgPath
        imageVW.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }  i have tried but same.. i declared that shape layer on the top and given all values in the awakeFromNib finally i set the path from layout subviews